# How can I break my data into 2 separate groups?

Tags: r

I need to make a graph showing the prices of 4 different stocks over time, but they need to be in groups of 2 in their own graph. I have made individual graphs of each stock, but not sure how to group them together.

Here are my four stocks. I need them grouped as such (AAPL & MSFT) and (AMZN & GOOGL)

```
Symbol = c( "AAPL", "MSFT","AMZN", "GOOGL")
```

This is my code creating the charts themselves. I am using facet_wrap to create multiple charts.

```
 gg <- ggplot(DataX) + aes(x=Date, y = Price, fill = Symbol, color = Symbol) +
  geom_line() + transition_reveal(Date) + facet_wrap(~Symbol)
```

Here is a picture of what I have: https://ibb.co/Fz7dLnZ
Here is a picture of what I am looking for: https://ibb.co/KNkjrM2

Comment: Please note that R and Rstudio are separate pieces of software. You can use R without Rstudio and your question is not related to the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres one approach:

```
DataX <- DataX %>% 
   mutate(group = ifelse(Symbol %in% c("AAPL", "MSFT"), "AAPL vs MSFT", "AMZN vs GOOGL"))

gg <- ggplot(DataX) + aes(x=Date, y = Price, fill = Symbol, color = Symbol) +
  geom_line() + transition_reveal(Date) + facet_wrap(~group, ncol=1)
```